# How to turn intervals into coordinate pairs?

Tags: intervals

So for the function `(x^3 + 2)/(x^4 + 1)` I needed to find the values where it is increasing and decreasing. I used

```
Reduce[D[f[x], x] > 0, x] // N
```

to find where it is increasing. Then I used

```
Reduce[D[f[x], x] < 0, x] // N
```

to find where it is decreasing. When I run that code I get

```
-2.11198 < x < 0. || 0. < x < 0.372591
```

and

```
x < -2.11198 || x > 0.372591
```

So my question is how do I turn those answers into coordinate pairs? To look like this: `(-2.111985,0)∪(0,0.372591) and (-∞,-2.111985)∪(0.372691,∞)`

Answer (score 5):

```
sol1 = -2.11198 < x < 0. || 0. < x < 0.372591;
sol2 = x < -2.11198 || x > 0.372591;

region1 = List @@ (ImplicitRegion[#, x] & /@ sol1);
region2 = List @@ (ImplicitRegion[#, x] & /@ sol2);

rb1 = First @ RegionBounds[#]& /@ region1
```

> {{-2.11198, 0.}, {0., 0.372591}}

```
rb2 = First @ RegionBounds[#]& /@ region2
```

> {{-∞, -2.11198}, {0.372591, ∞}}

For displaying in the desired form:

```
HoldForm[# \[Union] #2]& @@ rb1
```

> {-2.11198, 0.} ⋃ {0., 0.372591}

or

```
Infix[foo @@ rb1, "\[Union]"]
```

> {-2.11198, 0.} ⋃ {0., 0.372591}

Similarly, for `rb2`:

```
HoldForm[# \[Union] #2]& @@ rb1
```

> {-∞, -2.11198} ⋃ {0.372591, -∞}

```
Infix[foo @@ rb2, "\[Union]"]
```

> {-∞, -2.11198} ⋃ {0.372591, -∞}